# porque el valor de mi variable no se modifica en c++

Tags: c++, funciones

estoy haciendo un programa donde al momento de elegir una funcion de compra donde se le resta el total a una variable la cual ya se le asigno un valor inicial, pero despues de regresar al menu principal la variable regresa a su valor inicial sin las modificaciones.

```
int main(){

do{

    int opc=0;
    float creditoDisponible = 10000;

    cout << "Banca movil UP" << endl;
    cout << "Que desea hacer" << endl;
    cout << "1: ver credito dispobible" << endl;
    cout << "2: comprar" << endl;
    cout << "4: Salir" << endl;
    cout << ": " << endl;
    cin >> opc;

    switch (opc) {

        case 1:
            cout << "Su credito disponible es: $";
            cout << creditoDisponible << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            comprar(creditoDisponible);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Opcion no reconocida" << endl;
            break;


    }

}while(true);
```

en la funcion de arriba esta la variable credito la cual ya le puse el valor de 10,000, al momento de elegir la opcion de comprar la cual es la siguiente

```
int comprar(float creditoDisponible) {
int opc1, opc2, opc3, opc4;
cout<<"Que productos desea adquirir"<<endl;
cout<<"Credito disponible: "<<creditoDisponible<<endl;

cout<<"Recargar telefono escriba la cantidad a recargar: "<<endl;
cin>>opc1;

cout << "Pagar recivo de luz, escriba la cantidad a pagar: "<<endl;
cin>>opc2;

creditoDisponible = creditoDisponible - opc1 - opc2;

cout<<"Credito disponible: "<<creditoDisponible<<endl;
```

}

una vez finalizada esa función se regresa de nuevo al menu principal, pero si le doy a la opción de mostrar credito disponible me muestra la cantidad inicial sin las modificaciones antes hechas.

Comment: Estoy seguro de haber visto una pregunta muy parecida. `creditoDisponible` en la función `comprar` es un parámetro. Los parámetros son variables locales que viven en la función que están. Necesitas pasar el valor por referencia si quieres que afecte a la variable homónima en la función `main`.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `creditoDisponible` pasa a la función `comprar` por copia y las modificaciones las haces a la **copia** de dicha variable, manteniendo la **original intacta**.

Seguramente querías pasar la variable por **referencia**:

```
int comprar(float &creditoDisponible) {
//                ^ <--- Referencia a variable float
    int opc1, opc2, opc3, opc4;
    cout << "Que productos desea adquirir\n"
            "Credito disponible: " << creditoDisponible << endl;

    cout << "Recargar telefono escriba la cantidad a recargar:\n";
    cin >> opc1;

    cout << "Pagar recivo de luz, escriba la cantidad a pagar:\n";
    cin >> opc2;

    creditoDisponible = creditoDisponible - opc1 - opc2;

    cout << "Credito disponible: " << creditoDisponible << endl;
}
```